# Appfabric Cache Perfmon Errors

Tags: appfabric, perfmon, appfabric-cache

We have a critical system that is highly dependent on Appfabric Caching. The setup we use is three nodes which serves around 2000 simultaneous connections and 150-200 requests/second.

Configurations are the default ones. We receives maybe 5-10 "ErrorCode:SubStatus" each day which is unacceptable.

I have added some performance counters but I can't see anything weird except that we sometimes see values on "Total Failure Exceptions / sec" and "Total Failure Exceptions" is increasing but one 2-3 times a day.

I would like to see what these errors comes from but I can't find them in any logs in the Event Viewer (enabled them all according to documentation). Does anyone know if these errorc could be logged somewhere and/or if it possible to seem them in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> We receives maybe 5-10 "ErrorCode:SubStatus" each day which is
>   unacceptable.

Between 5 or 10 errors per day, with  150 requests/sec per day ?. It's quite anecdotic. Your cache client have to always handle properly caching errors. A network failure can always occurs.

5-10 "ErrorCode:SubStatus" is quite obsur. There are more than 50 error codes in AppFabric Caching. Try to get exactly these error codes. See full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334279%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

> would like to see what these errors comes from but I can't find them
>   in any logs in the Event Viewer (enabled them all according to
>   documentation). Does anyone know if these errorc could be logged
>   somewhere and/or if it possible to seem them in any other way?

The only documentation available is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334238%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). The event viewer is useful to regularly monitor the health of the cache cluster. However, when troubleshooting an error, it is possible to get an even more detailed log of the cache cluster activities. I'm not sure, this will help you a lot because it's sometimes too specific.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I totally missed the correct error code, what we see is ERRCA0016 -> ES0001 -> ConnectionTerminated.

We also see some ERRCA0017 -> ES0006 which I guess is quite normal to see.

Thanks, will have a look at the logging section.